# Ubuntu not booting properly on Dell Inspirion Mini 1012

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, ubuntu-netbook

I've got a dell mini that I procured from a friend of mine and decided to install linux on it instead of the OOB WinXP. I originally had CubLinux installed and it worked just fine, but it wasn't what I was wanting. I then tried to install the latest ubuntu, but could never get to the install screen so I went all the way back to 10.04 which worked pretty well but is old and I could not perform any updates on it.

After trying lubuntu 17.04 and xubuntu 17.04 I am finally able to get to a somewhat working solution with xubuntu 16.04. The only way for me to get into the OS is by selecting the Upstart kernel option and then starting lightdm from the command line. If I don't, then the system will either sit at a black screen forever or at the xubuntu loading screen. My only options at that time are to power off the netbook then power it back on as the keyboard stops responding.

I've selected the additional drivers for the processor, tried gdm3 and have added a sleep option to the lightdm config but neither of these seem to have resolved my issue.

I'm well versed in RHEL/CentOS server systems but not so much with ubuntu or client systems. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and viewing the logs noted that it failed n loading the wireless drivers.  The install with lubuntu 17.10 completed with the network cable connected.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error messages you are getting?

Comment: Reviewers: Although this *looks* like it's not an answer, I think it's actually giving a solution: to connect the machine to the Internet with an Ethernet cable during installation. *user820522*: Still, I agree with @SDsolar; this answer would be more useful if you were to include some specific details of your similar issue. Note also that if your intent here *is* to try to find a better solution to your problem, rather than to offer a solution here, then you should post a new question instead.